# Asp.Net Session Lost After Https

Tags: asp.net, session, https, 2checkout

I am trying to integrate 2Checkout payment into my asp.net 4.0 website and everything is working except the annoying thing that the Session is lost when the browser navigates to the checkout/payment page at 2 checkout.

I am pretty sure the problem is that the browser switches from http to https and back to http.

I tried to set a HttpCookie to solve the problem, but that didn't work.

How do I configure (probably something in web.config) the website, so that the session is still good after the redirect back to my own website?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731782.aspx - I believe you want the value 'New ID On Secure Connection' set to false in IIS.

Comment: It seems like that page is written for classic ASP. I am using asp.net 4.0

Comment: It's an IIS wide setting - we had something similar when we moved to 2008 R2 and setting this value fixed it. The crucial difference between our situation and yours though is that we were staying on the same domain (.net 3.5 http to .net 3.5 https). It's worth a try though.

Comment: Also, out of interest, are you sure the session isn't expiring? You could check in Session_OnStart and Session_OnEnd

Comment: I tried to set that setting but it didn't change anything. Just as a little extra info, when I go back from 2checkout, it opens my own website in a new tab. On chrome, I am at the login page (session has disappeared), in IE I get a server error. The session timeout is the usual 20 minutes and the "shopping" takes like 2 minutes

Comment: Unless the app pool is recycled in the meantime or similar which is another reason why the session could have disappeared - it's just worth checking that something else isn't going on.

Comment: A few quick web searches suggest it might be browser related - see here for starters for IE8. Also worth approacing the 2Checkout people and asking them if they've had customers experience the same thing.

Comment: I have come up with a solution which may be a bit weird, But it seems to work. I am basically taking the Session["user"] and putting it into the Application["user" + userid]. When I return from the checkout, I check whether the returned "pass through" userid is in the Application["user" + userid] and then create the session again and remove the Application variables, so that it sort of appears like the session was never interrupted. It works in IE and chrome. I don't know if it is a very horrible solution, probably is ha ha. But it works :)

Comment: Post it as an answer for future generations :-)